# Display child items main navigation

Tags: 8, navigation

I created child elements for the main navigation. I went into the block configuration and adjusted it to show up to three levels of sub menu's.

For Drupal 7 I know that I used Nice Menu's to get the menu working with child links. But it's not usable yet with Drupal 8.

I was wondering if there was another module or how I could get my Child Links to show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to go to the menu configuration and manually check "expanded" for each item that has children. This is really annoying since there used to be a checkbox right on the list of links so you could do it on a single page at once. Not anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't originally check it because I didn't want it always expanded but then I was like... oh I'm going to be hiding it with css and such so I feel a little... duh why didn't I think of that